# Can you scroll to an anchor in html of an element that is relatively positioned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
        <li name="services">
            <h1>Services</h1>
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li name="about">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li name="portfolio">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li name="team">
            <h1>Team</h1>
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li name="process">
            <h1>Process</h1>
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li name="packages">
            <h1>Packages</h1>
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
    </div>
```

This HTML is relatively position on the page. When I try to direct the page to '#services' it does absolutely nothing. It just loads the page again. I am assuming the problem is that they are relatively positioned. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to direct the page to '#services' it does absolutely nothing. It just loads the page again

I don't think relative positioning is the problem. The fragment identifier (hash) takes you to an element with the `id` value matching the hash, or the `a name=` element with the `name` equal to the tag (note that that's an anchor, an `a` tag, not just any tag). Your `li` tag doesn't match either of those criteria. (In fact, I don't believe that [`li` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) are allowed to have a `name` attribute.)

If this structure is unique on the page, try changing

```
<li name="services">
```

to

```
<li id="services">
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/opetor)

For years it was a well-kept secret (I certainly didn't know about it for *years*), but it *was* [covered in the HTML 4.10 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id).

Comment: ah... ok thanks, I thought it was the name value not the id, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an anchor `<a>` tag:

```
<a name="services"></a>
```

Comment: Yes...in 1997 or so. ;-) Seriously, the fact that browsers target elements by `id` with the fragment identifier (hash) seems to be a very well-kept secret, and yet, even IE6 does it. This use [was covered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) in the HTML 4.01 specification. (I didn't realize it back then either.)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `a` tag with a `name` element - you can't just attach `name` to any tag

```
<li><a name="packages"></a>
    <h1>Packages</h1>
    <p>text</p>
</li>
```